# LocomotiveCMS 2.2.3 issue assets not loading https

Tags: locomotivecms

I'm hosting a locomotiveCMS engine on heroku. I just upgraded the engine to 2.2.3 everything worked fine, except that now all assets are failing to load. After I looked at the source code I saw that all assets (like css, js etc) are referenced via "https" to my s3 bucket and thus not working.

I'm using the liquid tags like "{{ "main" | stylesheet_tag }}" and don't know why they resolve to "https"

Thanks
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding these 2 lines to following to carrierwave.rb:

config.asset_host = 'http://.s3.amazonaws.com'

config.fog_public = true

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

  config.cache_dir = File.join(Rails.root, 'tmp', 'uploads')

  case Rails.env.to_sym

  when :development
    config.storage = :file
    config.root = File.join(Rails.root, 'public')

  when :production
    # the following configuration works for Amazon S3
    config.storage          = :fog
    config.fog_credentials  = {
      :provider                 => 'AWS',
      :aws_access_key_id        => ENV['S3_KEY_ID'],
      :aws_secret_access_key    => ENV['S3_SECRET_KEY'],
      :region                   => ENV['S3_BUCKET_REGION']
    }
    config.fog_directory    = ENV['S3_BUCKET']
    config.asset_host     = 'http://<my-bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com'
    config.fog_public = true
  else
    # settings for the local filesystem
    config.storage = :file
    config.root = File.join(Rails.root, 'public')
  end

end
```